# Delphi displays question marks when reading from MS Access

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-7, tadoquery

I installed a new Windows 7 on my computer.

I have a delphi 7 application that is using `TAdoQuery` to select from MS Access data from a table that has hebrew letter.

In Access the data is saved okay.

The system Locale is having Hebrew as the non-Unicode language.

But when fetching the data from the table delphi shows the hebrew letters as question marks (`?`).

Any idea please?

Code example:

```
with qryCustom do
begin
  Close;
  SQL.Text := 'select * from TB_Files where ID > 0 order by ID';
  Open;
  while not EOF do
  begin
    lItem := lvFiles.Items.Add;
    lItem.ImageIndex := 1;
    lItem.Caption := FieldByName('FullFileName').AsString;
    Next;
  end;    
  Close;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `AsWideString` instead of `AsString`.

And if possible/feasible, try switching to a Unicode-enabled component, like the old TNT components.  Delphi 7 controls do not natively support Unicode.  As long as the OS locale matches the data locale, you should not lose anything from Ansi/Unicode conversions.  But you really should not rely on that.  Better to go full Unicode as much as possible

Comment: But AsWideString does not exist in Delphi7

Comment: `TField.AsWideString` may not have existed, but `TWideStringField` did, and it had a `Value` property that returned a `WideString`. What value does `FieldByName('FullFileName').ClassName` return? If it returns `'TWideStringField'` then you can type-cast to access its `Value`.